# To pass in a variable and filename as parameters to a SQL file in Powershell

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, sqlplus

I have a master and a sub script as PowerShell scripts. From the Sub PowerShell script, a SQL file is called. I am looking to pass in a variable to the SQL from Master script through the sub script. I can see it is coming to sub script but is not coming to SQL file.

Master Script has below;

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server_temp -FilePath E:\PshellScripts\ErrorChecks_Sub.ps1 -argumentlist $batchname
```

Sub script has below;

```
$password = get-content E:\SQL\config\access.txt
$sqlParameters = "powerShellVar='$args'"
& E:\Oracle\BIN\sqlplus.exe schema1/$password@env1 @E:\env1\SQL\Batch_Jobs_Error_Check.sql -Variable $sqlParameters
```

Batch_Jobs_Error_Check.sql has below;

```
set echo off
set doc off
set pagesize 9999
set linesize 300
set feedback off
set verify off
set pause off
set flush off
set heading on
set newpage none
set termout off
set trimspool on

spool E:\logs\Batch_Jobs_Details\Batch_Error.DTA;
select *
from batch_error where  batch_name like '$($powerShellVar)';
spool off;
exit
```

In the above sample, file name is hard coded. I would prefer if the filename can be dynamically assigned as the '$($powerShellVar)'_error.dta

Could you have a look and let me know please?

Thanks,
Mary

Comment: My immediate guess is this doesn't work because `batchname` and `batch_name` are spelled differently (notice the underscore `_`)

Comment: batch_name is a column name in batch_error table. batchname is the variable coming from PowerShell script. So that shouldnt cause an issue.